# JavaScript code works in debug mode and doesn't work in release

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, filereader

I am trying to do validations for csv file which is being uploaded while reading a file, for which am using the FileReader()

The entire logic works perfect in debug mode but doesn't work in release.

```
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            var allTextLines;


                new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            allTextLines = reader.result.split(/\r/);
            setTimeout(() => resolve(allTextLines), 1000); // (*)

        //  return allTextLines;

        }).then(function(result) { // (**)

            alert(result); // 1
            var headers = result[0].split(',');
            return headers;
            //return result * 2;

        }).then(function(headers) { // (***)

            alert(headers); // 2
            var massUploadCount = 0;
                 for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length - 1; i++) {

                     var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
                     if (data.length == headers.length) {


                         var tarr = [];
                         for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                             if (headers[j].toUpperCase().trim() === 'ITEM NUMBER') {
                                 var itemNum_regex = /^[\d]{0,10}$/;
                                 if (!(itemNum_regex.test(data[j]))) {
                                     console.log("hello from polo");
                                     massUploadCount++;
                                     com.ws.mdmui.common.showDialog("Error", 'Please enter correct value for ' + headers[j] + ' in row ' + i);
                                     return;
                                 } else {
                                     tarr.push(data[j]);
                                 }
                             }
             }
         }
     }

     return massUploadCount;

        });
```

Comment: Debug mode of what? The browser? Release where? To a server? Also i dont see you using an `onload/onloadend` event for your filereader that will cause timing issuses as you wont know when the file has actually been read

Comment: debug mode in chrome browser. release mean normally when i try to upload csv file and check validations without break points in chrome.   Also I used the onloadend function , it didn't make any difference

Comment: your `alerts` would probably mess with actual results ... what do you expect at `alert(result); // 2`

Comment: @JaromandaX   i corrected it , Thats a typo

Comment: you probably have something between `reader.readAsBinaryString(file);` and `new Promise(function(resolve, reject)` that you haven't shown, because there's no onload event listener for the asynchronous `reader.readAsBinaryString(file);` - or, you must be stepping through the code you posted in a debugger of some sort

Comment: how can `pasting` produce a typo?

Comment: If you used the onloadend event then you probably implemented it wrong. Please show your attempt to use it, note your promise calls would need to be called within the event handler

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks, moving the validation logic to onload event worked.